# looping problem while appending data to existing text file

Tags: java

```
     try {
     stmt = conn.createStatement();
     stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
     stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
     rs = stmt.executeQuery("select cust from trip1");
     rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("select cust from trip2");
     rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("select cust from trip3");
      File f = new File(strFileGenLoc);
      OutputStream os = (OutputStream)new FileOutputStream(f,true);
      String encoding = "UTF8";
      OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, encoding);
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);


 }


       while ( rs.next() ) {

         while(rs1.next()){

              while(rs2.next()){

         bw.write(rs.getString(1)==null? "":rs.getString(1));
             bw.write("\t");
         bw.write(rs1.getString(1)==null? "":rs1.getString(1));
         bw.write("\t");
         bw.write(rs2.getString(1)==null? "":rs2.getString(1));
         bw.write("\t");

         bw.newLine();

              }
         }
     }
```

Above code working fine.
 My problem is 
   1. "rs" resultset contains one record in the table
   2. "rs1" resultset contains 5 record in the table
   3. "rs2" resultset contains 5 record in the table

"rs" data is getting recursive.

while writing to the same text file , the output i am getting  like

```
1   2    3
1   12   21
1   23   25
1   10   5
1   8    54
```

but i need output like below

```
1   2    3
   12   21
   23   25
   10   5
    8    54
```

What things i need to change in my code.. Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
while ( rs.next() ) {

     bw.write(rs.getString(1)==null? "":rs.getString(1));

     while(rs1.next()){

          while(rs2.next()){        
              bw.write("\t");
              bw.write(rs1.getString(1)==null? "":rs1.getString(1));
              bw.write("\t");
              bw.write(rs2.getString(1)==null? "":rs2.getString(1));
              bw.write("\t");

              bw.newLine();

          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: @Dean... i already tried this one.this is not working

first row is printing correctly, but from the second row "the 2nd column data shifted to "first column" place since the first column is blank"

Comment: This will output the first column first time and then "" for each time there after, assuming \t separator, what do you want to put in the first column for subsequent records?

Comment: if there any "data" from database it should place that or else blank space in first column

Answer (score 0):

You must join the three tables using a common column (often called foreign key). The values in the tables `trip2` and `trip3` say to which entry they belong in table `trip1`. Then you can do this:

```
select t1.cust, t2.cust, t3.cust
from trip1 t1 
  join trip2 t2 on t1.id = t2.trip1_id
  join trip3 t3 on t1.id = t3.trip1_id
order by t1.id
```

Now, you will get all the results in a single result set. To get the output you want, print the first column (`rs.getString(1)`) only when it changes.

Comment: @ Aaron.. its mandatory to run the 3 query's separately(otherwise it leads to some tedious problem in my application).so i couldn't join the query.

Comment: In that case, you must emulate the join with a couple of `HashMap`. Don't forget to order all records by the same key!

Answer (score 0):

The logic here is flawed.  If you only get one result in rs2, you would only show one row, as your `while(rs2.next())` will be false after you run through it once.  One option would be to iterate over all your result sets, put the values into arrays, and then iterate over them to put the lines to your file.  A better solution, as intimated by @Aaron Digulla, would be to only return a single `ResultSet` from your database.